# XMLSerializer serializeToString escape characters ><

Tags: javascript, xmlserializer

I have a XML file which i want to convert to string in java script code. It works fine except one thing.The XML file has on line like below,

.....other lines....
< Source Data>< /Source Data>
.....other lines....

It shows other lines perfectly but for < Source Data>< /Source Data> lines it displays only < Source Data/> in console log. < Source Data> is omitted somehow. I am using below code to display ,

var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlFile);
console.log(xmlString)

Please explain me why it is happening and how to resolve this issue to display properly. please note, there is no space after less then character "<". i am putting as it was not displaying here properly without that

Thanks in advance

Comment: In xml "<a></a>" is same as "<a/>". Basically the second is a shortcut to write the first example.

Comment: is there any way to surpress  this and show it as original ?

Comment: is there any way to make XMLSerializer() ignore the internal changes and shows as original xml text lines